# Keeping the local state store updated in a Kafka Streams app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a log compacted topic in Kafka which I am reading in a KTable and creating a store. Whenever I update a keyed message I don't see the latest state when the app is running. But I am able to see the updated state when I restart the streams application. How to get the updated state while the streams application is running without a restart.

Here's the code (in main function) that I am using to iterate the values from the state.

```
final String queryableStore = metaTable.queryableStoreName();

    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String,String> metaTableView = null;
    try {
        metaTableView = waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(queryableStore,QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore(),streams);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    metaTableView.all().forEachRemaining(row -> logger.info("Key: "+row.key+" Value: "+row.value));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you run the code. But if I understand it correctly, you expect that `logger.info` prints each update? If this is the case, than this will not work, because `.all()` iterates over the KTable once and terminates afterwards. Pay attention, that you are using "Interactive Queries" in your code example that are design for one-time lookups. You would need to re-run the query in your own code -- of course, you would get *all* record each time.

If you want to get the KTable updates continuously (and only the updates), you need to work with the KTable directly. For example, you could do

```java
KTable table = builder.table(...);
table.toStream().foreach(...);
```

Each update to the KTable will produce an output record that is processed by `foreach()`. Pay attention to record caching; you might want to disable caching to get all updates, otherwise, some updates might not be forwarded as they are subject to caching.